# trying to write a query with Table A,B where Cond1: A.pc=B.pc & Cond2: (preferred (A.sub = B.Sub) or else any 1 row that meet only Cond1)

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I trying to get the result table to contain rows where

```
Condition1: A.pc=B.pc AND 
Condition2: (preferred (A.sub = B.Sub)  or 
             else any one row that satisfy only Condition1)
```

I have tried the following inner join query and few other join and sub-query but can not figure out exact way to write a query with above strange condition.

```
SELECT * FROM tblA AS A INNER JOIN tblB AS B
ON A.sub=B.sub
WHERE A.pc=B.pc


tblA
-------------------
| id  |  pc | sub |
-------------------
| 0   | 5   | abc |
| 1   | 8   | def |
| 2   | 6   | ghi |
| 3   | 2   | jkl |
| 4   | 7   | mno |
| 5   | 19  | pqr |
-------------------

tblB
-------------------------
| pc  | sub | uml | ull |
-------------------------
| 3   |arm  |  1  |  1  |   
| 3   |gtk  |  1  |  2  |
| 3   |lmn  |  1  |  3  |
| 3   |pop  |  1  |  4  | 
| 5   |abc  |  1  |  5  |
| 5   |hlq  |  1  |  6  |
| 5   |pon  |  2  |  1  |
| 5   |qrt  |  2  |  2  | 
| 7   |alo  |  2  |  3  |
| 7   |mno  |  2  |  4  |
| 7   |ghm  |  2  |  5  |
| 7   |stm  |  2  |  6  | 
| 9   |mck  |  2  |  7  |
| 9   |plo  |  3  |  1  |
| 9   |rtk  |  3  |  2  |
| 9   |ert  |  3  |  3  |
| 6   |gji  |  3  |  4  |
| 6   |ghi  |  3  |  5  |
| 6   |yux  |  4  |  1  |
| 6   |del  |  4  |  2  |
| 2   |jkl  |  4  |  3  |
| 2   |jll  |  5  |  4  |
| 2   |uin  |  6  |  1  | 
| 2   |tro  |  6  |  2  |
| 19  |ppm  |  6  |  3  |
| 19  |kde  |  6  |  4  |
| 19  |grp  |  6  |  5  |
| 19  |sho  |  6  |  6  |
-------------------------


Expected Result Table:
-------------------------------
| id  | pc  | sub | uml | ull |
-------------------------------
| 0   | 5   |abc  |  1  |  5  |
| 2   | 6   |ghi  |  3  |  5  |
| 3   | 2   |jkl  |  4  |  3  |  
| 4   | 7   |mno  |  2  |  4  |
| 5   | 19  |ppm  |  6  |  3  | * 
-------------------------------
* notice this is a arbitrary row as (A.sub=B.sub) not found
** notice there is no result for id=1 as pc=8 do not exist in tblB
```

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT * FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON ((A.sub = B.sub) OR (A.pc = B.pc))` ?

Comment: because then the result table will contains 4 row for ID=1, 4 row for ID=3 and so on and so forth. please see the result table for expected result

Comment: Did you try my propised solution ? Did it work for you ? If it helped you solve your problem, please **[mark it as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Comment: @ExpertSystem No I didnt use your solution. Instead what I did was create a temp table using `SELECT * FROM tblA AS A INNER JOIN tblB AS B ON A.pc = B.pc GROUP BY B.pc` query. then update the temp table with `UPDATE tmptbl AS A, tblB AS B, tblC AS C SET A.sub=B.sub, A.uml=B.uml, A.ull=B.ull WHERE B.sub=C.sub` and it does exactly what i needed. Temp table originally gets filled with arbitrary values, then gets updated with proper values for all the 'sub's that exist in TblB. I needed the temp table for other reasons as well. but wonder if can be written as `UPDATE (SUB QUERY) AS A SET ...`

Comment: In that case, consider writing it as a solution and accepting it (for the reasons already stated). Also, please post a new question regarding your `UPDATE...` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until someone comes up with a better answer, here is some code that does what you want.
Please, note it might not be a good solution in terms of performance (espcially as your tables grow).

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT tblA.id, tblB.* 
      FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB 
        ON tblA.pc = tblB.pc AND 
           tblA.id NOT IN (SELECT tblA.id 
                             FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB 
                               ON tblA.sub = tblB.sub) 
      GROUP BY tblA.id
  UNION
    SELECT tblA.id, tblB.* 
      FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB 
        ON tblA.sub = tblB.sub 
    GROUP BY tblA.id
  ) AS tu
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50d6cd/74)**.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it I came up with is to repeat a join condition in where clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblA AS A
    INNER JOIN tblB AS B 
        ON A.pc = B.pc
WHERE A.sub = B.sub 
OR A.pc = B.pc
```

Comment: it works for most part except result table contains 4 row for ID=1, 4 row for ID=3 and so on and so forth. as (else any one row that satisfy only Condition1) is not specified in the above query. please see the result table for expected result. any way to include (else any one row that satisfy only Condition1)?